# Is there an end to the Hall of Trials?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I recently purchased Recettear, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is an end to the Hall of Trials. I've so far made it to the third floor of the dungeon before dying. It says that if you die, you can only bring one item you found back out with you, but if you finish, you can bring everything. I'd really like to nicely stock my item shop, but I'm wondering when the end is in sight!

Comment: You've gone a long way since this question. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dungeon ends on level 5.

Comment: technically, it only had 4 dungeon levels... as level 5 is *different* in a good way ;)

Answer (score 3):

There certainly is an end to the hall of Trials, it is simply the introduction dungeon.
Just keep on pressing and you find it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 5th floor.